# InfoBoxBuilder gmaps4rails v2 not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, gmaps4rails2

My map handler is

```
map_handler = Gmaps.build('Google', { markers: { maxRandomDistance: null }, builders: { Marker: InfoBoxBuilder} });
```

I already added in my layout:

```
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src/infobox_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

and also I already added a file infoboxbuilder.js.cofee in my assets with this override:

```
class InfoBoxBuilder extends Gmaps.Google.Builders.Marker # inherit from base builder


 # override method
  create_infowindow: ->
    return null unless _.isString @args.infowindow

boxText = document.createElement("div")
boxText.setAttribute("class", 'yellow') #to customize
boxText.innerHTML = @args.infowindow
@infowindow = new InfoBox(@infobox(boxText))

@bind_infowindow()

  infobox: (boxText)->
    content: boxText
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-140, 0)
    boxStyle:
      width: "280px"
```

But when I load the site I get this javascript error with no map:

```
ReferenceError: InfoBoxBuilder is not defined
```

Comment: load order matters in js

Comment: WHat order should it be? I have gmaps scrips in head before my <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> And my asset pipeline is
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .

Comment: map_handler creation should be called after you load the required js library

Comment: I already tried creating the handler via console, after everithing is loaded and still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized your mistake

Replace

```
 class InfoBoxBuilder
```

With

```
class @InfoBoxBuilder
```

fyi, `@` tells coffeescript to attach the object to the window object.

Comment: Thanks, it totally made the magic. I took that class directly from the documentation https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Change-handler-behavior.

Comment: Sure but look at the video, I create the map within the same file, so the class is accessible

Comment: Btw beware, remove `@bind_infowindow()` if you upgrade to 2.1